# Access is Denied in java.io.FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, text-files, java.util.scanner

I'm using Eclipse, if that helps.

I have to access files in java using a Scanner, and I'm using them to generate objects. Some of the objects have dependencies on other objects, and the program is supposed to call the appropriate "builder" method for these objects.

For example, I have an `Effect` class, which is used by the `Weapon` and `Artifact` class, which are used by the `Enemy` class.

The methods for generating these are called `effectBuilder(String fileName)`, `weaponBuilder(String fileName)`, etc. There's no issues with any of these methods but the `enemyBuilder(String fileName)` method, which gives me a `java.io.FileNotFoundException: .\doc\Builders (Access is denied)` error. The file location is where I'm keeping the text files for these methods.

The enemyBuilder method is as follows:

Class:

```
public static Enemy buildEnemy(String fileName)
{
    Scanner sc;

    //creates Scanner, prints error and returns null if file is not found

    try {
        sc = new Scanner(new File("./doc/Builders/"+fileName));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

    //values are put into constructor at the end of the method.

    String n = sc.nextLine();
    int h = sc.nextInt();
    int d = sc.nextInt();
    int lo = sc.nextInt();
    int hi = sc.nextInt();
    String g = sc.nextLine();

    ArrayList<Weapon> weps = new ArrayList<Weapon>();
    while(!g.equals("a") && sc.hasNextLine()){
        weps.add(Builder.buildWeapon(g));
        g = sc.nextLine();
    }

    ArrayList<Artifact> facs = new ArrayList<Artifact>();
    while(sc.hasNextLine()){
        facs.add(Builder.buildArtifact(sc.nextLine()));
    }

    sc.close();

    //converting for constructor purposes

    Weapon[] warr = new Weapon[weps.size()];
    int x = 0;
    for(Weapon e : weps)
        warr[x++] = e;

    Artifact[] aarr = new Artifact[facs.size()];
    x = 0;
    for(Artifact e : facs)
        aarr[x++] = e;

    return new Enemy(n, h, d, lo, hi, warr, aarr);
}
```

The other `builder` methods do similar calls to other `builder` methods to create new objects, but this is the only one causing any problems.

For reference, here is a sample of the txt file that is being used (The information in parenthesis details what variable the data should be used for):

```
Warrior (should be n)
12 (should be h)
10 (should be d)
15 (should be lo)
30 (should be hi)
battleaxe.txt (first instance of g in 1st loop)
longsword.txt (second instance)
a (signifies the computer to move to next while loop)
battlemedallion.txt (first instance of g in 2nd loop)
chestplate.txt (second instance)
```

Is there a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the error is really this one : `java.io.FileNotFoundException: .\doc\Builders (Access is denied)` then it seems you're trying to open a directory, which means `buildEnemy` is not called with a valid filename

Comment: From the rest of the message, it gets stuck right when it tries to call one of the other `build` methods with `g` for the first time. Is there anything that would be causing it to read the wrong line?

Comment: Found the error, I guess the calls to `nextInt()` were causing some weird behavior with the following `nextLine()` calls, switching them to `next()` cleared the error and allowed the method to run normally. It was trying to call the `build` method with an empty string, which is where the problem was.

Comment: @GoonyKnightMan No. The problem was that you couldn't open the file. Constructing the `Scanner` failed. You couldn't possibly have executed either `next()` or `nextInt()`.

Comment: I assume it was on a previous file, containing filename to transmit to each builder, is that it GoonyKnightMan ?

Comment: @EJP, yes, but I think it was caused by the 2 `nextInt()` calls, because it ran those fine but then crashed trying to use String `g` in the `buildWeapon()` call within the first while loop. Changing `String g = sc.nextLine()` to `String g = sc.next()` solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Is filename parameter empty string then file may not be accessed.

Check the permissions of the file you may not have rights to read the file as the user you are trying to read the file.